# Angle brackets on Apple keyboard with Windows 10 & Bootcamp

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows

I have an Apple Magic keyboard with Numeric Keypad (Spanish layout) and running Windows 10 with Bootcamp. Works well **except the angle brackets symbols: greater-than (>) and less-than (<) are not in the expected key on the keyboard**. Instead of being left to the 'z' character, they are left to the '1' character. Other characters such as 'ñ' are correctly mapped.

Windows has Spanish language installed and set the keyboard to Spanish QWERTY.

Which keyboard configuration maps the angle brackets correctly?

Comment: What does the key next to z produce?  Having angle brackets next to 1 is what happens when the machine thinks the keyboard is ANSI instead of ISO.

Comment: I am not in front of the keyboard right now bit I think its The ° symbol.

Comment: Do the keys work correctly when you are working in macos?

Comment: Yes. On macOS the keyboard works perfectly.

Comment: As Tom mentioned, I think you need to change the keyboard from ANSI to ISO. I had a similar problen in macOS Mojave. Changed my Keyboard Type to ISO and selected "Spanish - ISO" (not Spanish) in my Input Source